# How is this not closed under addition?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$U = \left\{[x,y]^T \middle|\, x^2 = y^2\right\}$$

My way of understanding it, is that if you have $(x,y)^T$ in the subspace, let's say $x=2$ and $y=2$ or any vectors s.t. $x^2=y^2$ then you can add another two vectors of the same type (where $x^2=y^2$) to get another value of $x^2=y^2$, ie:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
(2)^2 = (2)^2 \\
(3)^2 = (3)^2 \\
\end{array}\right.
\implies
(2+3)^2 = (2+3)^2.$$

lol I thought of the answer while typing this.

Counterexample to prove it's not closed under addition:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
(2)^2 = (2)^2 \\
(3)^2 = (-3)^2
\end{array}\right.
\qquad\qquad
(2+3)^2 = 5^2 ≠ (-1)^2 = (2-3)^2.$$

Comment: thanks MickG, I gotta learn how to format before my next post

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier counterexample. We have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2 \cr 2\end{pmatrix},\; \begin{pmatrix} 2 \cr -2\end{pmatrix}\in U,
$$
but of course the sum is not in $U$, since $4^2\neq 0$.

Comment: +1, though I suspect OP might need it spelled out even more!